# Correct way for thread safe indexing operator in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, indexing, thread-safety

I want to have thread safe indexing operator and I came with the following code which seems to work.
Can you see any problems with it except for bounds checking?
Is there a better way to do the same thing (with overloading indexing operator, not with get/set functions)?

```
class A
{
public:

A()
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        v[i] = i + 1;
    }
};


    class Proxy
    {
        int* val;
        A* parent;
    public:
        Proxy(int& a, A* p) : parent(p) 
        {
            parent->z.lock();
            val = &a;
        };

        ~Proxy()
        {
            parent->z.unlock();
        }

        int operator=(int a) 
        {
            *val = a;
            return a;
        };

        operator int() const
        {
            return *val;
        };
    };


int operator[](int i) const
{
    z.lock();
    int r = v[i];
    z.unlock();
    return r;
}


Proxy operator[](int i)
{
    return Proxy(v[i], this);
}


int v[100];
Z z; // some locking mechanism, not important

};
```

Comment: Do  not use lock/unlock pairs, but a guard object handling the unlock. Do not lock elementary data, you my  have a wider scope.

Comment: Thanks Dieter, the pairs were just for illustration, in that case I am just looking for better readability of the code, not for performance

Answer (score 0):

Since the locking mechanism isn't specified I'd assume it uses a normal mutex in which case the obvious problem is this:

```
A a;
a[0] = a[1];
```

Put differently, it is very easy to dead-lock the program. This problem is avoided with recursive mutexes.

The other obvious problem is that the code depends on copy-elision which is not guaranteed to always happen. If the copy is not elided upon return the temporary will release the lock and the copy will release it again which normally is undefined behavior. In addition, access to the member is unguarded and will potentially introduce data races. To avoid this problem you should define a move constructor and make sure that the moved from state doesn't try to release the mutex, e.g.:

```
A::Proxy::Proxy(Proxy&& other)
    : val(other.val)
    , parent(other.parent) {
    other.parent = 0;
}
A::Proxy::~Proxy() {
    if (parent){
        parent->unlock();
    }
}
```

The not so obvious issue is that it is unlikely to result in an efficient implementation.

Comment: Thank you Dietmar Kühl
Your comments was very helpful in generic case.
I am usually thinking in terms of critical section, which is recursive, but will consider this when needed.
Also current case is about build in types without any performance considerations, so copy-elision shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @kamerunka: it seems you haven't understood my comment about copy-elision: if a copy is _not_ elided, your code does _not_ work!

Comment: now I see your point, actually I haven't thought of assigning one element to other, because I don't have such usecase, but this is valid point.
One interesting observation with VC10
If I have:
    private:
        Proxy(const Proxy&&);
        Proxy(const Proxy&);
The program does not compile

If I implement any of the constructors above and have it public, it is just never called, obviously Proxy instance is created in place and neither moved, neither copied.

Comment: @kamerunka: the copy/move for the return value is most likely elided (sometimes referred to RVO). However, there is not giarantee that it is done which is why the copy or move ctor is required. The generated will just do the wrong thing if it is not elided.